# Angual 6 event emitter - does not work

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-event-emitter

Can anyone please spot what is wrong in this code, I am not getting event back to appcomponent

test1.component.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mytext1" >
<button 
  id="clicked" 
  name="Click Me" 
  class="button"  
  (click)="returnData();">
  Click Me! 
</button>
```

test1.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test1',
  templateUrl: './test1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test1.component.css']
})
export class Test1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  @Input() mytext1: string;
  @Output() dataEmit: EventEmitter < string > = new EventEmitter < string > ();;

  ngOnInit() {}

  changeText1($event) {
    this.mytext1 = $event;
  }

  returnData() {
    console.log("button clicked");
    this.dataEmit.emit(this.mytext1);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <app-test1 [mytext1]="childmessage" (returnData)="getTest1Data($event)"></app-test1>
  {{testText2}}
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'AngularDemo';
  public testText2: string = "from parent";
  childmessage: string = "I am passed from Parent to child component";

  getToggle($event) {
    this.testText2 = $event;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

I am not getting a response on app.component.ts, neither getting a debugger.

Comment: instead 

getToggle($event) {
   this.testText2 = $event;
 } 

code is 

getTest1Data($event) {
    this.testText2 = $event;
  }

Comment: in your html template, you write that the getTest1Data function is supposed to be triggered when the event is emitting. But there is not function getTest1Data in your component ts.

Comment: Neither is there an `Output` binding called `returnData`

Comment: Thanks for response, but i was using 

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    title = 'AngularDemo';
    public testText2:string="from parent";
     childmessage : string = "I am passed from Parent to child component"

     getTest1Data($event) {
       this.testText2 = $event;
     }

     ngOnInit(){
    
     }
    }

Comment: Just have a look at this StackBlitz Project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kk8jwr

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong binding to the event emitter. You need to bind to the `Output` parameter, not to the function which emits (`dataEmit` instead of `returnData`) event and replace `getTest1Data` with `getToggle`

```
<app-test1 [mytext1]="childmessage" (dataEmit)="getToggle($event)"></app-test1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output name is `dataEmit`. So refacto your component call from this

```
   <app-test1 [mytext1]="childmessage" (returnData)="getTest1Data($event)"></app-test1>
```

to this:

```
   <app-test1 [mytext1]="childmessage" (dataEmit)="getTest1Data($event)"></app-test1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<app-test1 [mytext1]="childmessage" (returnData)="getTest1Data($event)"></app-test1>
```

(returnData) should be (dataEmit)

dataEmit is the actual event (of type eventemitter) returnData is just a method called on click of the button :)

Also getTest1Data($event) should be getToggle($event)

Hope this helps.